# Objective-C calling javascript in UIWebView calling back Objective-C; threading issues

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView-based application that is storing some state. I have a native tab bar and upper bar however. What I need is that when I click on the native bar, I persist the data stored in the UIWebView.

To do this, I called evaluateJavaScriptByString to create a JSON object and it does a callback to objective-C via the UIWebViewDelegate protocol.

However, I find that the callback is asynchronous and hence my main transaction happens before the data is loaded.

Any idea how this problem can be solved?

Update: To explain the problem better:-

- I have an HTML page with a form that someone puts some data into.
- My Tab bar is native.
- On the click of a button on the tab bar, I want the data from HTML saved to an Objective-C model, and the view should change to some other view.

What is happening is that once I click the button, the javascript call happens to the page (to create a JSON string to send to Objective-C) and this data does get saved to the obj-c model. However, this happens asynchronously. So my screen changes before the data is loaded into the model. If I refresh the next screen it shows the correct data. I was wondering if there was a way around this.

Note, I know how to call OBjective-C functions from WebViews. We are using JSOBjBridge for that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just add something like this `@"some_var = MAKE_JSON(); window.location = \"myapp://callback/\" + escape(some_var)"` at the end of your javascript code, that you transfer to evaluateJavaScriptByString:

In UIWebView's delegate implement webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: and catch all urls with `myapp://` prefix like this:

```
- (BOOL)           webView: (UIWebView *) webView
shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest *) request
            navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType) navigationType {
    NSString *url = @"myapp://";
    NSString *path = request.mainDocumentURL.relativePath;
    NSString *callbackURL = @"callback/";
    if ( [path hasPrefix:url] ) {
        path = [path substringFromIndex:[url length]];
        if ( [relPath hasPrefix:callbackURL] ) {
            NSString *json = [path substringFromIndex:[callbackURL length]];
            //TODO: Work with json
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return [super webView:webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType: navigationType];
}
```

I didn't test this code, I just written it from scratch, but it should work, I already did it in this way.

Comment: This is already happening using JSObjBridge. The problem isn't that. To explain the problem better:-

Comment: If i understood right, you can return NO in tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController: and manually change tab when data will be written to your model, it can be done using notificationcenter. Anyway, what is JSObjBridge? Is it yours or 3rd party?

Comment: Yes JSOBjBridge is third party but is pretty standard to invoke Obj-C functions from Javascript. Will need to understand notificationcenter.

Comment: If you can modify source of JSOBjBridge, add sending notification when data received from WebView, and in your application call addObserver for this notification. === If you can't modify JSOBjBridge, you need to use Key-Value-Observing for observe changing model's data.